# Can I deep fry in my Le Creuset dutch oven?

Tags: equipment, cookware, cast-iron, deep-frying, dutch-oven

It's an enameled cast iron dutch oven. Just wondering if I could take off enamel by deep frying in it.

Comment: I assume that you're referring to their enameled cast iron.  If that's incorrect, please edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

The enamel coating is put on by a high temperature process, much higher temp than the 300-400 F that you would deep fry in, so it will be safe to fry in.

The concern that this raises for me is the difficulty in cleaning if you fry repeatedly. After a few batches, there will be a film of oil that will form just above the level of the oil in the pot you are frying in. If you thoroughly clean it, it will not be a big deal, but left alone it will build up.

Also, deep frying in a heavy  pan is unnecessary, as you really want to get hte oil hot, and the extra thermal mass of the pan would just take extra heat. It is not bad to do so, but a thin aluminum pan works just as well for frying.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have many other options for pans that have a wide enough bottom. I have an aluminum stock pot, but the sides are too high. I have a 12 inch saute pan, but the sides are too low.

Comment: how are the sides too high? I guess you mean difficult to get food in/out with the high sides?

Comment: Also, hello from a B-more transplant, hun. Lived in Charles Village for many years - worked in Federal Hill...

Comment: It's probably worth buying a super-cheap aluminium or steel pan for the purpose. It will get ugly, but it won't matter. A purpose made pan with a correctly fitted deep fat frying basket will be safer too.

Comment: Yes -- difficult to get food in and out. I don't deep fry much, so I'm not looking for any more equipment here. (You know if you say "hon" now, you need to pay Denise Whiting (Cafe Hon) royalties).

Comment: I do deep fry in mine, and Eric is correct - it is somewhat detrimental to the appearance of the enamel, though I don't think it actually damages anything. A good scrubbing with Barkeeper's Friend helps.

Comment: Actually, one of the advantages of the heavy pot is that it keeps a steadier temperature. That helps to resist things cooling down when you add food to the oil, and generally makes it easier to keep in a steady range rather than overheating and overcooling in cycles.